# AVL tree vs Heap

Tags: data-structures

Suppose a company wants to develop an application to collect and store the temperature statistics of different countries. The city wise temperature details from all the countries are collected from different online spreadsheets. Some of these spreadsheets contain sorted data and others contain semi-sorted data (chunks of data are sorted).

The main requirement of the application is that it should be able to store and search for data quickly. It means if you want to store a country’s temperature stats in this application, it should be able to store it quickly and if you want to search for a specific city’s temperature, it should provide you with fastest possible search.

You are hired by this company to develop this application and you are provided with two options of data structures to choose from:

AVL Tree
Heap
Which data structure you will prefer to use when

Data is sorted

Data is semi-sorted

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Yes it is kind of homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big advantage of a heap is to be able to get the max or the min element in constant time through max-oriented or min-oriented heap.

The lookup time in O(n) will be worse than an AVL tree, you just know that each node is bigger or smaller than its children so you cannot reduce the problem by going left or right like in an AVL tree.

Since your problem only states lookup and insert (not retrieving the max or min T) i would go with AVL tree which can implement both operations in O(log N)

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend AVLTree Data Structure . AVL tree data structure is a powerful tool for organizing data objects. It is equally useful for organizing multiple
data objects like that of hierarchical relationships.
AVL Tree is a data structure which is used to manage the large amount of data at one place and access of data is much faster.

Comment: Will AVL tree will be useful in both circumstances when date is sorted or semi sorted?